# Why I get undefined method each_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-rails

When I try to deploy my app, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method each_key' for false:FalseClass /var/deploy/dcaclab/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.6/lib/tinymce/rails/asset_manifest.rb:41:ineach'
/var/deploy/dcaclab/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.6/lib/tinymce/rails/asset_installer.rb:26:in cleanup_assets' /var/deploy/dcaclab/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.6/lib/tinymce/rails/asset_installer.rb:13:ininstall'
/var/deploy/dcaclab/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.1.6/lib/tasks/tinymce-assets.rake:12:in `block in '
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Where you are deploying your application?

Comment: to digital ocean via cloud66

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I tried the answer below, but it didn't seem to help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

First please check your production.rb file under config/environments

Set these line there

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Then run this command to compile your assets for production

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

However if you wish to include tinymce-jquery.js independently, you will need to add it to the precompile list in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile << "tinymce-jquery.js"
```